# Forcing a figure strictly on a separate page

Tags: floats, positioning

How can a figure be forced to appear *alone* on a separate page?  `\begin{figure}[p!]` forces it to a separate page, but it does not guarantee that some other small figures (which I'd like to be included inline in the text) will not accidentally end up on the same figure page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting the interfloat space `\@fpsep` to at least `\textheight` guarantees that figures on float pages will appear alone on a page:

```
\makeatletter
\@fpsep\textheight
\makeatother
```

Also here, the figure remains vertically centered, this is not affected. You can change `\@fpsep` also mid-document. Using `\afterpage` (requiring loading the `afterpage` package) for changes could be handy, such as:

```
\makeatletter
\afterpage{\global\setlength\@fpsep{8\p@ \@plus 2fil}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Nice. Can this be done for only one specific float?

Comment: Can `\@fpsep` be changed mid-documnet?

Comment: @lockstep: yes! @Martin: yes: we could modify `\@floatsep` again but let a `\clearpage` before the next figure(s). Or we do it by `\afterpage{\global\setlength\@fpsep{...}}` I added it to the answer.

Comment: Where should I put this code? I've tried putting the first block of code you've given as an example within the figure, right before the figure, and right before the chapter starts which is a few pages before where the image is currently placed. Nothing of them worked — the image is still not on a separate page.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Try as I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: Nice.  But it's still unclear where to put this code...  Referring to the two codeblocks in your answer, I tried putting the first codeblock before my figure, and the second codeblock after it.  This has no effect on the figure itself, but causes my 2-column document to print only one column per page after the figure in question.  I tried other permutations with no luck.  Could you specify where the code should go?

Comment: @EdwardNewell The figure already needs to be on a float page. Not on a normal page. Perhaps post a new question with your specific code.

Answer (score 28):

I think your best shot is to use the `\afterpage` command from the `afterpage` package, which will put your actions as soon as the current page is over. This avoids that you ends with half pages blank. 
So I suggest you do the following:

```
\afterpage{%
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\clearpage
}
```

The problem of the other pictures is not completely solved if you have floats which are not placed before the `\afterpage` command, but it should ensure that no floats after this command are placed on the same page of the picture you want alone.

Comment: I found that this method throws an error message, but is fine if the \clearpage is placed above the figure. This seems to agree with the documentation page found here http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/afterpage.pdf

Comment: This answer works well for me, but why is the `clearpage` required?

Comment: @lucidbrot The idea is to have the picture on picture-only pages, and the text or other pictures on other pages (per the question asked). If you don't use clearpage, you will end up with your following text after the picture, which will not be alone. You could use newpage to create a new page, but if you have other floats (for instance, picture), they might appear on the new page, which clearpage avoids. You can remove clearpage if you don't mind having the text on the same page of the picture (after it), but it kinds of defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 12):

\clearpage

> The \clearpage command ends the
>   current page and causes all figures
>   and tables that have so far appeared
>   in the input to be printed.

Comment: If I place the `\clearpage` right after the `figure` block, it'll break the text (cause half an empty page).  I don't want to break the flow of the text, just insert a separate page, reserved only for one figure.  The `p!` option of `figure` will give me that separate figure page, but it won't guarantee that no other figures will end up on the same figure page.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**

```
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.1}
```

**Long answer:**

You can control in some extent page floats by means of `\floatpagefraction` that is the minimum part of a page that has to be occupied by floating objects before a ‘float page’ is produced, or in  two columns documents also with `\dblfloatpagefraction`, that indicates the minimum part of a page that has to be occupied by two column wide floating objects (`figure*`) before a float page.

Disclaimer: With this approach, if the next float is enough small and have also the `[p]` option, obviously still it could be included in the same float page. Unfortunately, another easy options as `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}` and set  `\floatsep` seem to  work only for normal text pages.  If this is a problem, it must be enough put text between both page floats (to fill at least one  page)  **or** be sure that the next float have not the `[p]` option, or forget this approach and set  `\@fpsep` as perfectly explained by Stefan (or `\@dblfpsep` for texts in two columns).

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{A}
\caption{A normal float}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{B}
\caption{A page float}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{C}
\caption{Another normal float}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```