# Not in outer par mode error produced by a single word

Tags: errors

While compiling a LateX file I keep on getting the following error message:

> ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.400 \end{document}
>
> ?

I get this error from a text containing this sentence:

```
In Yang the authors review the application of process mining
```

If I remove from the text above the word "mining" the error disappears. I am using MikTeX 2.9 and the editor TexWorks 0.6.1. This looks to me as a bug but reinstallation of MikTeX did not fix the problem.

I think I need a methodological approach to spot the source of the error. Any suggestion on what I could do?

**Further details**

As suggested below by *egreg* I have removed all \marginpar instruction but that did not fix the error. Then I removed all embedded figures and this fixed the error. It looks like the offending block of code is the following:

```
\afterpage{
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Time elapsed for critical activities}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Triage-FibrinolysisElapsedTime}
    \label{fig:tfet}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
}
```

I do not know what is wrong in this block of code, but if I comment it the error disappears. What I do also not know is why this is block of code, that is at the end of the document, makes an error appear when I add the a single word at the beginning of the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That error is only issued in contexts of floats (`figure` or `table`) and `\marginpar`.

Comment: The methodological approach most recommended for the *TeX world is to isolate the error by constructing what is known as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) or 'MWE' (see also [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: What's the reason for `\afterpage`? I see none. You just want `\begin{figure}[p]`.

Comment: The use of \afterpage to force the figure to be in a separate page (it is a pretty big figure) is suggested at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/forcing-a-figure-strictly-on-a-separate-page

Comment: Removing \afterpage as suggested by egreg completely fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, for lack of information, what the cause for the error is. However, for a ”pretty big figure“ (but also for *all* figures) the best approach is to do

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
<code for the figure>
\caption{...}\label{...}
\end{figure}
```

I'm not saying that the `\afterpage` trick has no value, but it should be attempted only in rare cases when the final figure positioning is awkward and no other method succeeds.

Never use the `[h]` option alone.

Comment: Egreg, thanks for very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately it was not enough to fix my problem. I realized that I was having also a problem due to the twocolumn format that required the use of the figure* environment of whose existence I was not aware. See  [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document] for details.